# codeigniter4 controller routing in subfolder

Tags: controller, routes, subdirectory, codeigniter-4

I have this setup in Routes:

```
$routes->add("admin", "Admin/Login::index");
$routes->add("login", "Admin/Login::index");
$routes->add("admin/home", "Admin/Admin::index");
```

my controller directory is like this:

[image: folder structure]

Problem:
when I access:

```
http://mydevsite.vhost/admin/home
http://mydevsite.vhost/login
```

both are working as I want it,
but this link:

```
http://mydevsite.vhost/admin
```

returns 403 Forbidden.

how should I write my route or controller to make /admin goes to the same place as /admin/home or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurred because I have a folder in my public folder that shares the same name with my folder in controller which is "admin" so when i access /admin it search for index.php inside public/admin.

and more info about routes

```
$routes->add("admin", "Admin\Login::index");
$routes->add("login", "Admin\Login::index");
$routes->add("admin/home", "Admin\Admin::index");
```

that is the correct syntax, using / will cause an 404 error when the link have a variable segment.